# Web Server with Multiple Domains

Tags: domain, webserver, hosting

I am running a Web Server which has single dynamic IP and many websites are running on several different ports. The server I am running are IIS7 and WAMP. I have around 5 websites in total running each on different port.

I also have 5 different domains of .com tld. Can I point each domain to different port keeping the same IP address? If yes, is there a guide? I am using Namecheap as my domain provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Domains cannot be pointed at a port. If you want each domain to point at a different web application on the server then you will need to configure each virtual host on the web server to either use a reverse proxy, or perform a rewrite or redirect to the corresponding port.

Comment: Can IIS7 and Apache both do that?

Comment: I know HTTPd can. Not sure about IIS7.

Comment: Ok can you please link to an article which describes it? Or your own written article with your experience?

Comment: Which part do you want to know about, virtual hosts, reverse proxies, redirects, or rewrites?

Comment: Either reverse proxies, redirects or rewrites. You tell me which is the most efficient to do the thing I want. 5 domains need to be pointed to 5 web apps at same IP with different ports.

Comment: I already have 5 virtual host on Apache which are working fine on different ports.

Comment: So then why not just put them all on port 80?

Comment: you know one app can be on one port? how can multiple apps be on single port?

Comment: HTTP 1.1, created almost 7 years ago, adds the `Host` header which allows a single HTTP server to serve multiple domains on the same port.

Comment: Is there a guide?

Comment: Oh wait, I lie. It was 14 years ago. http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html

Comment: Google "IIS virtual host", here's knowledge base from Microsoft.com: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816576 How to create a new virtual server or Web site in Internet Information Services (IIS) 6.0, hope it will work with IIS 7

Comment: I don't understand what are you referring to saying HOST header but it feels like reading HOST attribute from header I can check which is the domain and then I can point it to specific folder of app. But is this how the Shared Hosting Provider works?

Comment: You don't need to read it; the web server already does.

Comment: But how actually shared hosting works? They allows us to use multiple domains pointing to different folders.

Comment: The web server reads the `Host` header and uses the appropriate virtual host configuration for the value.

Comment: ok got it. How to configure Apache for this? Is there an article?

Comment: The `ServerName` directive identifies the `Host` value that you want the virtual host to handle.

Comment: I updated things and put www.mydomain.com in ServerName. I also created A record for domain to point to my IP address with default port 80. It's always redirecting to 80 and not where it should redirect.

Comment: Cheer! I managed to get this work!